# Subset in Python output error - HackerRank

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, subset

***This is a question from [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-check-subset)***

You are given two sets `A` and `B`.

Your job is to find whether set `A` is a subset of set `B`.

If set `A` is subset of set `B` print True.

If set `A` is not a subset of set `B` print False.

---

Input Format:

The first line will contain the number of test cases `T`.

The first line of each test case contains the number of elements in set `A`.

The second line of each test case contains the space separated elements of set `A`.

The third line of each test case contains the number of elements in set `B`.

The fourth line of each test case contains the space separated elements of set `B`.

---

Output Format:

Output True or False for each test case on separate lines.

---

Sample Input:

```
3
5
1 2 3 5 6
9
9 8 5 6 3 2 1 4 7
1
2
5
3 6 5 4 1
7
1 2 3 5 6 8 9
3
9 8 2
```

---

Sample Output:

```
True 
False
False
```

I coded this and it worked fine. The output and expected output matches but the output is claimed to be wrong. I even checked if it was because of any trailing whitespace characters. Where am I going wrong ?

```
for i in range(int(raw_input())):
    a = int(raw_input()); A = set(raw_input().split())
    b = int(raw_input()); B = set(raw_input().split())

    if(b<a):
        print "False"
    else:
        print A.issubset(B)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem specification says this:

> Note: More than 4 lines will result in a score of zero. Blank lines won't be counted.

Your solution uses 7 lines, so it counts as a failure.

Comment: Oops ! You are right. Worked now with only `print A.issubset(B)`

Answer (score 0):

**In Python-3**
##Hackerrank##
##Check Subset##

```
for i in range(int(input())): 
    a = int(input())
    A = set(input().split()) 
    b = int(input())
    B = set(input().split())
    print(A <= B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = int(input())
ans  = []
for i in range(t):
    A = int(input())
    a = list(map(int,input().split()))
    B = int(input())
    b = list(map(int,input().split()))
    check = 0
    for c in range(A):
        if(A>B):
            check = 0
            break
        else:
            for j in range(B):
                if(a[c]==b[j]):
                    check = 1
                    break
                else:
                    check = 0
        if(check == 0):
            break
    if(check == 1):
        ans.append('True')
    else:
        ans.append('False')
    del a
    del b
print('\n'.join(map(str,ans)))
```

Comment: without the use issubset(), Works fine with Python 3 I hope it will help you

Comment: Hey, It is highly recommended to explain the answer a bit and not just paste a blob of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(int(input())): 
   a = int(input())
   A = set(input().split())
   b = int(input())
   B = set(input().split())
   print(A.issubset(B))
```